# Cancel or interrupt SKAction.moveTo (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to cancel or interrupt `SKAction.moveTo`?

For instance, let's say there is this code:

```
let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: 2.0)
let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
item.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
```

And 1 second into the `moveTo` action, we want to reroute the object. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Sure! Look into the similar method `runAction(withKey:)`. If you subsequently run another action with the same key, it'll replace the existing one completely. If you just want to stop the action without giving it a new one, you can use `removeActionForKey()`.

Comment: On a related note, is it generally better to move actions through one big moveTo (e.g., moving 200 pixels) vs multiple smaller moveTo in the "update" function (e.g., moving 20 pixels with each moveTo)?